# Is it possible to run one habor instance which accept push request of private images and proxing images from the dockerhub?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry, harbor, docker-repository

Im trying to setup a private Docker Registry with Harbor which is capable of storing "private" docker images and serving docker images from the Dockerhub.

Is there a way how I can run only one Harbor Instance?

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it seems that you want to setup a private registry with Harbor and also want Harbor to cover the work of proxying/being a mirror of Dockhub, right?

The challenge is Harbor does not support proxy/mirror function so far. A possible workable but not perfect solution you can try is caching all the images of Dockhub through the replication feature provided by Harbor. That required the Harbor version > 1.9.0.